# How can I parse and replace a word as a hashtag link when user types some text using flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

I want when a user types some text to make a post. But the thing is when the user types a hashtag (e.g. #avengers) I can parse and replace that hashtag with a link or ontap widget... Same goes with URL links

Comment: The hashtag is in the TextField also? Or it is in the post?

Comment: inside the textfield

Comment: Can you share the design of what you want?

Comment: @PhucTran it works the same way like facebook, youtube and instagram's hashtag system

Comment: @PhucTran I would show code but it's a lot

Comment: @DeadPool Did you find the solution about mentions,HashTag.can you pls suggest related to that.

Comment: @PhucTran Can you pls suggest an idea to implement mentions,hastags how to identify @,# to show popup list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to do this once the user has finished posting and not inside the typing bar:

The [smart_text_view 0.1.0](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/smart_text_view#-readme-tab-) package contains something called LinkTextSpan, which you can use to easily implement this on the view. Their example folder contains an example that was implemented.

As shown in the Flutter's Official Implementation [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/gallery/about.dart) for the Flutter Gallery Drawyer, you can do this:

```
_LinkTextSpan(
                style: linkStyle,
                url: 'https://something.com',
                text: 'flutter github repo',
              ),
```

and

```
_LinkTextSpan({ TextStyle style, String url, String text }) : super(
    style: style,
    text: text ?? url,
    recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()..onTap = () {
      launch(url, forceSafariVC: false);
    }
  );
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more about how this works - a snippet of code demonstrating how you would implement smart_text_view to parse hashtags will go a long way in helping me understand this better.